# Testing Approach for Audio and Video sessions

Tags: testing, video, automation, automated-tests, webrtc

I am looking for suggestions to test audio/video sessions (both manual and automation testing)

Example: Lets say there is a teacher who has 10 students and they are having an online session. There is a capability to talk (audio), video, share screen, maybe you can load YouTube videos or games as well, etc. (Like WebRTC connection)

Questions:

1. What could be the necessary test cases that can performed manually to test the reliability of the connection?
2. Is there a way to automate such scenarios?
3. If possible, what tool could be used to automated this?

Any suggestion or references would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver instances could help with automated testing, your questions #2 and #3. This [blog post](https://www.daily.co/blog/how-to-make-a-headless-robot-to-test-webrtc-in-your-daily-app/) goes into them in a bit more detail.